# Make retrofit leave out query parameters that are not set

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

While implementing filtering a list of items coming from a get request that required some query parameters to be sent. I ran into issues when some of the parameters were not set. The API call was sent with those parameters that were not set and sending them with their default values.

Comment: where is your code

Answer (score 1):

When you want retrofit to leave out @Query parameters that are not set, simply use the Boxed object of the primitve type you are sending to the endpoint, eg instead of int use Integer, instead of long use Long, double to Double.

That way if it is null retrofit would not bother adding it in the get request.